# Take ownership of files as admin

Tags: permissions, administrator, ownership

I'm somewhat new to Ubuntu but have been learning a lot on my own.   I am an admin user for my PC.  However, when I try to take ownership of most folders, like usr/local, it says I don't have permission and I'm not able to change any permissions.  It doesnt make any sense because I'm the only one who uses this PC and I'm an admin.  I even tried taking ownership using the terminal with no luck.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I'm also using Ubuntu 14.0

Comment: I think this post will help you a lot: [change ownership](http://askubuntu.com/questions/608322/changed-ownership-of-all-files-and-folder-in-home-to-root-by-mistake)

Comment: are you using `sudo`?

Comment: What command are you trying with the terminal?

Comment: There is a reason Ubuntu is more secure than Window. The admin user does not own the system files in folders like `/usr/local/`.  Messing with ownership of these files will probably give you a system that does not boot.  In general follow this advice: https://www.pinterest.com/pin/399342691928194426/

Comment: As discussed, don't do this. Or at least understand what you are doing, and maybe take a step back and ask what are you actually trying to achieve by hacking perms in `/usr`. What is the end-goal here?

Answer (score 4):

You can change the ownership of files using the `chown` command. Run `man chown` to read the documentation. In short, you can use it as `sudo chown USERNAME:GROUPNAME file`.

**BUT:**
I would not recommend changing the ownership of file outside your home directory! See [Changed owner of /usr/bin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132354/changed-owner-of-usr-bin) and [Changed permissions of / to user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108702/changed-permissions-of-to-user) to see what happens when you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the extension nautilus-admin could help you a bit to change your settings via a graphical user interface.

Comment: How? Can you provide a screenshot, or some instructions?

Comment: In the *answer*, please.